# Deploy .Net API to azure app service using github actions

Tags: azure-web-app-service, github-actions, .net-7.0, azure-appservice

I am trying to publish a .Net API to Azure app service. You can see the following workflow code,

```
name: Build and publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
      - master
      - publish-profile-path
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
      - master

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "./publish"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: "7.0.x"

      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore ./ABC.Solution/ABC.sln

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build ./ABC.Solution/ABC.sln --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish ./ABC.Solution/ABC/ABC.csproj --configuration Release --no-build --property:PublishDir='./publish'

  publish-dev:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/publish-profile-path'
    environment: Development

    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Development
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ABC-api-dev
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: "./publish"
```

This is the publish output,

[image]

I am getting the following error,

[image]

Any idea what the issue is? I tried to change the path but could not get it to work.

Comment: Change `package: ./publish` to `package: .` in your workflow.

Comment: @PravallikaKV it seemed to work. What is the explanation/reason? I am expecting the publish the files to /publish folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried with `package: ./publish` in my workflow and got the same error:***

[image]

AFAIK, this could be because `/publish` folder is not available.

If you face any issues while deploying using GitHub actions, Configure deployment directly in web app:

Navigate to `App Service=>Deployment center`, add ***GitHub*** as ***Source*** and fill the remaining details like select your GitHub organization and web app repository accordingly:

[image]

It generates **GitHub workflow** automatically to deploy the web app, check the workflow in `GitHub=>your web app repository=> .github/workflows`.

***I have deployed my .Net7 web api to Azure App Service using GitHub actions:***

**My workflow:**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - <webappname>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '7.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<webappname>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_E5176XXXXXXXXXXX }}
          package: .
```

**Deployed Successfully:**

[image]

[image]